# Ability to use multiple po files for localization asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, po, orchardcore

I'm using `OrchardCore.Localization.Core` NuGet package and follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) tutorial for making an asp.net core project localized.
everything is works well and fine, I have files like `en.po` and `fr.po` for localizations for english and french languages. but i want to separate some words into separate file like splitting po files into `en.po`, `fr.po`, `errorlist.en.po` and `errorlist.fr.po`.
I'm not looking for a smart way of separating some words just for a special files or etc. i just want to have some words in separate files to avoid having one big po file for each language.
I'm not quite sure i can't find any doc for this matter. Is `OrchardCore.Localization.Core` NuGet already have this feature? or can i implement something that can achieve this?

Comment: You can read about it on https://gist.github.com/sebastienros/7980aad2ab33dd3a1c011fcf5a3f350c#implementing-a-custom-logic-for-finding-localization-files
"In case some more complex logic is needed to locate PO files, the interface OrchardCore.Localization.PortableObject.ILocalizationFileLocationProvider can be implemented and registered as a service. For instance if PO files can be in a difference locations, or have to be found in a hierarchy of folders."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**
I asked this question on product own github issue list [here](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/3438) and i want to add the owner answer here for future reference, all credits to [Sébastien Ros](https://github.com/sebastienros):

On the same documentation page, it mentions you can provide your own logic to file the files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implementing-a-custom-logic-for-finding-localization-files

Which means you can copy this file:
https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/blob/dev/src/OrchardCore/OrchardCore.Localization.Core/ContentRootPoFileLocationProvider.cs

And adapt the `GetLocations()` method to your needs, by for instance listing all the files that end with the specific culture instead of returning a single `IFileInfo`.

Here is another example whe use in OC Framework to find file in multiple module folders:
https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/blob/dev/src/OrchardCore.Modules/OrchardCore.Localization/ModularPoFileLocationProvider.cs

Then you can register you provider like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationFileLocationProvider, MyPoFileLocationProvider>();
```

Comment: still getting one file for the same culture.